# Is this macro statement legal C++ or something else? And if it is legal how does it work

Tags: c++, macros, webkit, c-preprocessor

[WebKit](http://www.webkit.org) has a lot of pre-processor lines like this:
`#if MACRO1(MACRO2)`

For example:

```
#if PLATFORM(MAC) || (PLATFORM(QT) && USE(QTKIT))
#include "MediaPlayerPrivateQTKit.h"
#if USE(AVFOUNDATION)
#include "MediaPlayerPrivateAVFoundationObjC.h"
#endif
...
```

So my first thought was that they were function-like macros, but I can't see how that would work, and I couldn't find any #defines for these macros anywhere in the source code.

I asked another engineer what it was and he's never seen multiple macros used like that inside a #if before either. 
I found this [wiki page](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/Porting%20Macros%20plan) that talks about them but it still wasn't clear to me where they come from,

So my question then: Is this valid C++ or is it being replaced in the code by another tool/language like CMake or something else, and if it is valid C++ is there a spec anyone is aware of that talks about this?

I'm a support engineer for a C++ Static Analysis tool that isn't handling this syntax. A customer asked us to handle it, but if I'm going to take this to the senior engineer I'd like to not sound like an idiot :) So I'd like the nitty gritty if anyone knows it.

Comment: It says right there in the wiki page you posted the link for that those macros are defined in `Platform.h`, did you look for that file ?

Comment: Technically legal or not, if it builds with some compiler you support and a customer with enough clout wants it then you should consider supporting it anyway, at least behind a run-time flag, possibly even if it is macro-d in by CMake or something else. If it is CMake-d in then you could push it back to the customer to get them to make CMake to generate the actual code that gets compiled then static analyse that?

Comment: @John it may well be generated by the build scripts and not in the source checkout. Tradsud, have you actually tried building WebKit to see what it does?

Comment: Looks quite legal: http://ideone.com/osJuG.

Comment: posted PR at https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=65401

Comment: I had started the build process, but it got pretty hairy on Windows, so I hoped that the geniuses here would have an answer without me needing to install an old version if Visual Studio etc. And of course you guys answered it perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the wiki, in [root/trunk/Source/JavaScriptCore/wtf/Platform.h](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/JavaScriptCore/wtf/Platform.h) we get a definition for each of these defines.  For instance, the `PLATFORM` macro is defined as:

```
#define PLATFORM(WTF_FEATURE) \
       (defined WTF_PLATFORM_##WTF_FEATURE \
        && WTF_PLATFORM_##WTF_FEATURE)
```

The value of `WTF_FEATURE` will be replaced by the platform name to create some macro named `WTF_PLATFORM_WTF_FEATRE`.  For instance, with `WTF_FEATURE` passed into the macro as `MAC`, you would end up with a expansion of `WTF_PLATFORM_MAC`. The pre-processor `defined` directive combined with the logical `AND` is basically asking whether that macro value defined, and if it is defined, if its value is a "true" value.  You would use this macro somewhere else in the pre-processor like:

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
#define WTF_PLATFORM_MAC 1
#end if

#define PLATFORM(WTF_FEATURE) \
       (defined WTF_PLATFORM_##WTF_FEATURE \
        && WTF_PLATFORM_##WTF_FEATURE)

#if PLATFORM(MAC)
//...some code
#end if
```

You wouldn't use it within C++ code itself like

```
if (PLATFORM(MAC))
{
    //...some code
}
```

that would cause a bunch of errors from the compiler since `defined` is not a C++ keyword, and the evaluation and replacement of the macro within C++ code would end up dumping the `defined` pre-processor directive into any C++ code that directly called the macro. That's not valid C++.

Thanks you to Johannes for pointing out some of these issues.

Comment: Weird. The spec says "If the token *defined* is generated as a result of this replacement process or use of the defined unary operator does not match one of the two speciﬁed forms prior to macro replacement, the behavior is undefined.". Does that mean the code has undefined behavior? Or am I misreading this.

Comment: Unless I'm seeing something wrong, it doesn't look like *defined* is being generated as a result of replacement process taking place within the macro ... it looks to me like it's being applied as a unary operator ... so it's basically saying that `WTF_PLATFORM_##WTF_FEATURE` has to be something that is both defined *and* evaluates to a non-zero value.

Comment: @litb: after macro replacement occurs, the result will be well-formed as long as pasting together whatever `WTF_PLATFORM` and `WTF_FEATURE` resolve to is an identifier.  Then you'd have `define some_identifier`, which is one of the two specified forms.

Comment: @Michael we would have `defined some_identifier`, but that's undefined behavior, because the `defined` token is generated as a result of the macro replacement.

Comment: Okay, I see where the debate is coming in ... I believe this macro should be used in the pre-processor ... i.e., it would be used like `#if PLATFORM(X) ... #end if`

Comment: Thanks, I had poked around platform.h but somehow missed this, that makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 3):

The `#if` directive roughly works by replacing all macros, and then replacing all identifier and keywords of what's left by `0` and afterwards processing what's left has a constant expression according to the rules of the C++ language (the subset of those rules applicable to what's left from that replacing - quite little :)).

So `PLATFORM(MAC)` may yield a `1` if `MAC` is defined to be `1`, and a `MAC` if it is not defined, if `PLATFORM` is simply defined as

```
#define PLATFORM(X) X
```

The resulting `MAC` is an identifier and will later be replaced by `0`. It's more likely that they are concatenating the `X` to something like `PLATFORM`, so as to support multiple queries with `MAC` as argument, testing for existence of different macros. As a developer of a " C++ Static Analysis" tool you probably have access to the C++ spec. Take a look at clause `16.1`.

Comment: +1 for your last two sentences (although it was better pre-edit).

Answer (score 0):

The definitions may be coming from the build scripts. Most C++ compilers let you define macros on the command line.

One way I can see to define a USE macro like in your example would be:

```
#define USE_QTKIT 1
#define USE(x) USE_ ## x
```

Or maybe like:

```
gcc -DUSE_QTKIT=1 '-DUSE(x)=USE_ ## x'
```